# share local database with webapp and local service, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, database, google-chrome, service, local-storage

Im developing an web app, showing a counter for passages through a gate.
The webpage is run in an controlled environment (intranet), and is running Google Chrome as browser.(There is 10 gates to monitor = 10 setups)

The client computer has an optical trigger connected via USB, which sends the time stamp and some other parameters to the remote DB every time it gets triggered. this is done by a windows service running in the background. The service connects to the remote DB (SQL).

The website (running on the same computer as the trigger/service) is showing an counter with the number of passages. The website is checkng the remote database for changes every 3 seconds (prefered would be every second or less, but to reduce the traffic i use 3 seconds for now).

To lessen the traffic and minimize the risk for connection errors i would like to use a local database on the client computer. Its important that both Chrome and the trigger/service can access the database , syncing it with the remote DB every 5 minutes or so. **Is this possible?**

There is also an backend-page showing the status of all the gates, which gets the data from the remote DB, so its important that every passage is accounted for and updated to the remote DB.

I have been looking at indexedDB and webSQL but they seem not to be able to get data from outside Chrome. I have also been thinking of a local web server and database (SQL Express) on the client machines but it seems to be to much setup and making it difficult updating the application if changes are made to the application.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats right Chrome or any browser can access local data only if it is inside the browser sandbox. I.e. you cannot create a connection to local db or service on desktop. That would be a security issue.

I think WebSockets can help you here with connection to local service and also less traffic. You can run a local websocket server(any languagae you are comfortable with, google for available implementations) javascript can connect to this websocket server and receive real time updates. Javascript can now first write this data to websql and also send to remote db via HTTP. Even if you are not connected to remote server the data will be available locally.  As soon as the network is available data from websql can be pushed to remote.

So it ensures that your web browser is not pulling the data in infinite loop but receiving only when websocket server sends it. Same is true for sending the data to remote, send it when you have local data and connected.

inly catch here is that again you need websocket server on local computer but thats not a heavy weight thing. Yoy can cache data in memory uf browser is not up but I assume that is supposed to be up most of the time. So essentially your data is persisted in websql and remote db. Websql serves locally and also kerps it in sync with remote.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question @TechMaze. I have been looking on converting the application to a offline desktop app with TideSDK or something similar. With this approach i can read the file system directly, and with some minor tweaks to the IO-interface write to a file instead of directly to the remote DB. I even get the benefits of offline mode as you describe with web sockets.